Pyomo Expression should only be valid if the difference between Variable[t] - Variable[t+1] == 0
I need one of the constraints in my optimization to be valid only if the difference between the variable (of two consecutive times) is 0.
model.SOC = Var(model.T, bounds=(model.SoC_min, model.SoC_max))
def calendar_aging_rule(model, t):
 if t > 1:
  if model.SOC[t] == model.SOC[t+1]:
   return model.calendar_aging[t] == (-0.0000006084 * model.SOC[t]**2 + 0.0000028168 * model.SOC[t] + 0.0000614109) * 12 * model.idle[t]
 return model.calendar_aging[t] == 0
model.calendar_aging = Expression(model.T, rule=calendar_aging_rule)

but pyomo won't let directly implement this within the constraint.
I tried defining a binary variable and assigning 1, but couldn't get it to work either.

2 things wrong here.
First, you are directly comparing 2 floating point numbers with equals, which is generally a bad idea
Second, and the part that is fatal to your attempt at making a math program, is that you are comparing the value of 2 variables with that if statement, which is illegal.  The values of those variables are unknown when the problem is constructed so that statement doesn't work....  pyomo's job is to turn over a math expression to the solver and it cannot handle the if statement (between variables)

is there a way around this? how can i enforce an expression that should satisfy my optimization problem only when there is difference between the 2 consecutive variables (if it is possible)?

well, it isn't clear what the overall goal is.  You want to do "something" when the SOC is exactly the same out to many decimal points?

There isn't enough context here to give good advice, but maybe look at what would act upon SOC and then do something if that action is zero

I want the calendar aging expression to be applied to the optimization problem only if SoC[t]== SoC[t+1], else it should return 0, I tried using a big-M constraint with a binary variable. But the binary variable is always 0.
